# Image file urls still point to http instead of https

Tags: http

I just noticed that all my images in "Media" have the "http://...." URL under "File URL:".

I certainly have SSL installed and under Settings > General the domain is correctly set with https.
Is this set somehwere else or is there something else I could configure this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because the image (media) URL is stored as part of the record in the posts table. (Images/media are another type of post.)

You have several choices:

1. Manually change each media URL to https. This might take a while if you have lots of pictures. Not really recommended.
2. Use phpMyAdmin to change the value. There are several googles/bings/ducks on how to do this. But also not recommended - playing with the database can be dangerous.
3. Use a plugin to fix things. One such is "Better Search and Replace". It will do it all for you. Instructions are clear, and it is an established and well-supported plugin. It also has a 'test' mode that doesn't do anything, but shows you what would have been done. I have used this many times.

Also, make sure that you have changed your htaccess file to force requests to use HTTPS. Your hosting place will usually have instructions on how to do this.

Comment: The question seems to be referring the reported URL in the Media library. That URL is _not_ stored in the database. Only the path is stored.

Comment: Thank you both. Indeed, using "Better Search and Replace" fixed the issue. For any future readers. The wp_posts and wp_postmeta are the two databases that deal with media links. :)